# How to run Bittorrent-Tracker?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I found this torrent tracker on Git : https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker

I installed npm, and installed the package using `npm install bittorrent-tracker`

I went to the .bin directory and started the using `$ bittorrent-tracker --http`.
All seems to work and when I go to  http://localhost:8000/stats, the page comes up.

However, there is another way to start a tracker listed on the README file :

```
var Server = require('bittorrent-tracker').Server

var server = new Server({
  udp: true, // enable udp server? [default=true]
  http: true, // enable http server? [default=true]
  ws: true, // enable websocket server? [default=true]
  stats: true, // enable web-based statistics? [default=true]
  filter: function (infoHash, params, cb) {
    // Blacklist/whitelist function for allowing/disallowing torrents. If this option is
    // omitted, all torrents are allowed. It is possible to interface with a database or
    // external system before deciding to allow/deny, because this function is async.

    // It is possible to block by peer id (whitelisting torrent clients) or by secret
    // key (private trackers). Full access to the original HTTP/UDP request parameters
    // are available in `params`.

    // This example only allows one torrent.

    var allowed = (infoHash === 'aaa67059ed6bd08362da625b3ae77f6f4a075aaa')
    if (allowed) {
      // If the callback is passed `null`, the torrent will be allowed.
      cb(null)
    } else {
      // If the callback is passed an `Error` object, the torrent will be disallowed
      // and the error's `message` property will be given as the reason.
      cb(new Error('disallowed torrent'))
    }
  }
})

// Internal http, udp, and websocket servers exposed as public properties.
server.http
server.udp
server.ws

server.on('error', function (err) {
  // fatal server error!
  console.log(err.message)
})

server.on('warning', function (err) {
  // client sent bad data. probably not a problem, just a buggy client.
  console.log(err.message)
})

server.on('listening', function () {
  // fired when all requested servers are listening
  console.log('listening on http port:' + server.http.address().port)
  console.log('listening on udp port:' + server.udp.address().port)
})

// start tracker server listening! Use 0 to listen on a random free port.
server.listen(port, hostname, onlistening)

// listen for individual tracker messages from peers:

server.on('start', function (addr) {
  console.log('got start message from ' + addr)
})

server.on('complete', function (addr) {})
server.on('update', function (addr) {})
server.on('stop', function (addr) {})

// get info hashes for all torrents in the tracker server
Object.keys(server.torrents)

// get the number of seeders for a particular torrent
server.torrents[infoHash].complete

// get the number of leechers for a particular torrent
server.torrents[infoHash].incomplete

// get the peers who are in a particular torrent swarm
server.torrents[infoHash].peers
```

How do I start the server this way?

Comment: create that file, run it using `node`

Comment: @JaromandaX Do u know from where I should run it from? In the .bin directory. I am getting errors stating that objects aren't defined for infohash, onlistening.

Comment: indeed, the code does look incorrect now that you mention it

Comment: @JaromandaX Well thats wierd considering that this the sample code from the README file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but you can find a working example that will accept any infohash here: https://github.com/draeder/p2p-tracker.